# Create canvas thanks to slider filter using filtrr plugin

Tags: javascript, canvas

i'm creating a project to change color, contrast ... of a picture. I use filtrr plugin. I want to use slider to choose value of effect
It works well but it's not fast enough.

You can download plugin here to execute code : https://github.com/alexmic/filtrr/tree/master/filtrr2

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        #slider {
            width: 200px!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <img id="img" src="./o8rvhb.jpg">
    <canvas class="main" width="1024" height="512"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="./filtrr2.js"></script>
    <script src="./util.js"></script>
    <script src="./effects.js"></script>
    <script src="./layers.js"></script>
    <script src="./events.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            var i = 0;

            $( "#slider" ).slider({
                max: 100,
                min: 0,
                orientation: "horizontal",
                slide: function(t, e) {
                    $( "img" ).hide();

                    Filtrr2.fx( 'color', function( value ) {
                        value = Filtrr2.Util.clamp(value, -100, 100);

                        this.process(function(rgba) {
                            rgba.r += value; 
                        });
                    });

                    var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
                    canvas.setAttribute( "id", "test" + i );
                    canvas.setAttribute( "width", 1024 );
                    canvas.setAttribute( "height", 512 );

                    var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
                    canvasCtx.drawImage( $( "img" )[0], 0, 0 );

                    $( "body" ).append( canvas );

                    var newfilter = Filtrr2( "#test" + i, function() {
                        this.contrast( e.value ).color( e.value ).render();
                    } )

                    $( ".main" )[0].getContext( "2d" ).drawImage( $( "#test" + i )[0] , 0, 0 )
                    $( "#test" + i ).remove();
                    i++;
                },
                stop: function(t, e) {
                }
            });
        } )
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what do you want? A _faster_ plugin?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i would like a solution with this plugin or another way to do what i want if it's possible.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to really speed this up in any significant way, javascript is just not very good at image manipulation with its single-threaded non-accelerated style. If this is too heavy you might want to try and render them less often, reduce the frame rate or make your code more efficient in other ways (like, err, not loading the entirety of jQuery for a single plugin). Or render smaller images. I doubt we can really help you here - you are using the plugin as intended and its still slow.

Comment: ok but i don't understand why with glfs plugin it's fast : http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/. Is there another language that i can use for image manipulation. Thank's

Comment: The library you are pointing to is not the same library, it uses `WebGL` I presume (_its name is `glfx.js`). WebGL allows for much faster image processing, but you do need to learn to write `vertexShaders` and `fragmentShaders`. But yeah, that one link is fast because of WebGL. Why not use that?

Comment: It's a good library but i can't change hue of picture and i need it

Comment: http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/demo/#hueSaturation ?

Comment: it is not the desired result, i give you an example : https://gyazo.com/a9278e75f21b44dd51ecc49adb0892a2

Comment: Original picture : https://gyazo.com/08fd602c2b4b6fedb6ce47428198f1c5

Comment: IF what you are looking for is speed you should consider creating a native app, if you are going to be dealing with large high quality images the browser will slow you down... Maybe you can create something in the middle, show a small quick preview on the browser and then do the final render server side

Comment: Thank's i't a good idea but which languages can i use to create native app

Comment: Have a look at how the webGL plugin writes shaders, its usually in C sharp or something. Its strict but not too complicated. That code could easily carry over to native if you are so inclined. Good luck.